# ASP.NET Partial Postback form value problem

Tags: javascript, asp.net, updatepanel, postback

In my page_load I am creating a

```
HiddenField newField= new HiddenField();
```

and then I am assigning `newField.ID = "someid"` and `Value="0"` to it.   on a partial postback (triggered by an UpdatePanel) i am then checking

```
Request.Form["someid"]
```

in the panel_Load event during the postback.  but the request returns null as someid wasn't posted back. (not contained in the Request.Form collection) Why could this be?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason you're creating the field in code-behind and not in the ASPX?

Comment: yes, the fields are created for elements which are stored in a database. so they need to be created dynamically.. this is why I thought it was best to do it  in the updatepanel_Load event

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ASP.NET mangles the ID when rendered to the client by default.  To access it from the Form collection, try this:

```
Request.Form[newField.ClientID]
```

Comment: When creating the new field I also set the ClientIDMode to static so that I wouldn't need to do this. but this isn't the probelem because I set a breakpoint where I am checking the Request.Form value could view the AllKeys attribute of Request.Form  and no value for newField was posted back with any type of ID...

Comment: Are you adding the control to the controls collection of the update panel?  `UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.Controls.Add(newField);`

Comment: Thanks! :) I was adding to the update panel wrong, using UpdatePanel.Controls.Add instead of to the container.

Comment: @Jimmy No Problem. Word of advice: Next time include more code in your question. We could have spotted this if it was included in the question.

Comment: Ok sorry, I'll try to do that in future. when I'm accessing the hidden field's key in the updatepanel_Load method with Request.Form it looks like it's calling the key "ctl00$MainContent$newField" instead of just "newField" even though I set the ClientIDMode to Static. is there a way I can either prevent it from appending the ctl00$MainContent$  or  a way in which I can get the string "ctl00$MainContent$"  in the server side code so that I can lookup the correct key in Request.Form ?

Comment: Why not just use `newField.Value` after the postback instead of getting the value from the form collection?

Comment: well I don't know the newField's name... I have created the newField dynamically in the _Load method so I can't refer to it as newField in another section of the code. I also tried to do Page.FindControl("someid")  (where someid is the ID I gave to newField when creating it)  but that returned null

Comment: Why not?  Create the newField variable at the class level, then you can access it elsewhere.

Or you can do `UpdatePanel.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("someid").Value`

Comment: can't I make it post back the values with the key someid instead of ctl00$MainContent$someid ?

Comment: The postback uses the `name` attribute that is generated by the control (different from the ID), and unfortunately, the control doesn't expose that value in code to us.  ASP.NET uses this to populate the `value` property of the control object.

Comment: Oh right ok I see. well I'm trying your suggestion of declaring the HiddenFields at class level, and so I made a list List<HiddenField> itemFields = new List<HiddenField>();    and then am adding the fields to this list when I create them.  Later when trying to get the value I am using (from itemfield in itemFields where itemfield.ID == "item" select itemfield).Single().Value)  to get the value. But it seems the ID has changed because I get the exception that the sequence contains 0 elements. is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: oh well I found out why that was happening.. because the itemFields  list is empty (0 elements) when I'm checking it. so the postback causes everything to be reset (including the list) I guess? is that not what you meant by class level?

Comment: its getting reset because the load method is being re-run on the postback, essentially creating new controls.  Wrap the code where you create the control in a `if(!Page.IsPostBack)` check to prevent this.

Comment: hmm well I am already kind of doing that.. I have the code to create the HiddenFields in an if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1")  block.    so they are only created on the initial load and occasionally when a refresh is triggered... so the list shouldn't be empty when the code in updatepanel_Load executes?

Comment: I would ask another question regarding this issue.  You'll get some better support.

Comment: my updatepanel_Load actually looks like this:  if (!IsPostBack || triggeredRefresh.Value == "1") { create hidden fields } else if ( triggeredCheck.Value == "1" ) { lookup field values }

Comment: please help with my other (similar) problem here if you have time Kyle. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380320/asp-net-hidden-field-not-updating-after-postback  Thanks again