# ASP.NET hidden field not updating after postback

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net, postback

I  have some code on my ASP page which looks like this:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" id="updatepanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional" onload="updatepanel1_Load" ChildrenAsTriggers="false">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:HiddenField id="sendingRequest" runat="server" Value="0" />
....
</ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I also have some javascript on my page which does this, to trigger the update of the updatepanel:

```
var sendingRequest = document.getElementById("<%=sendingRequest.ClientID%>");
sendingRequest.value = "1";
__doPostBack('<%= updatepanel1.ClientID %>', '');
```

Everything works fine up to now, but in my updatepanel1_Load event, I try to set the value back to "0" :

```
sendingRequest.Value = "0";
```

This value never gets updated and set back to 0 on the client after the postback, and I can't figure out why!

Can anyone help? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [ASP.NET getting a hidden field's value after a partial postback...](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6379455/asp-net-getting-a-hidden-fields-value-after-a-partial-postback)

Comment: it's not a duplicate.. that was a problem with getting a hidden field's value when dynamically creating it in the server side code. Here my problem is that the hidden field's value isn't updating when created client side in the UpdatePanel ContentTemplate container

Comment: are you sure is not being set back to 1 (or loaded from viewstate) after you set it back to 0 on the server?

Comment: not intentionally.. could this problem be to do with there being a second updatepanel on the same page which is being refreshed every 5 seconds?  i don't see why it should affect the updating of the hiddenfield though since the hiddenfield is in a separate updatepanel

Comment: Is there any way you could post the complete .aspx page and code behind?  If nothing else, it will give us a little better context when reviewing your code.  Perhaps we could spot a better solution for you.

Comment: well not really.. there's a lot of code and most of it is completely unrelated. but I did find a way to fix the problem - I had a second updatepanel refreshing every 5 seconds and I fixed the problem by preventing it from updating when sendingRequest is set to "1". (so now it doesn't update until it's been set back to "0" by the server). it works but I don't really understand why since this hiddenfield isn't in the updatepanel which refreshes every 5 seconds! it seems like the second updatepanel was overwriting sendingRequest's value even though  sendingRequest isn't inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're having problems with a hidden field, you could use a TextBox instead. Hide the textbox with css (`display: none;`) to achieve similar results to a hidden field. Its not exactly pretty, but its a workable workaround.

Comment: I know it's an old thread. I just want to share my solution. Simply add the value to the `YourCtrl.Attributes["yourattname"]` property for any control that has view state enabled and it should work as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call registerstartupscript or something like that from server side. I can't remember exactly the method name but its part of page object. This will register any javascript you would like to execute after postback on the client side.

Comment: but it's not the javascript I'm having a problem with... the postback is working fine. it's updating the value during the postback which isn't working correctly

Comment: yes but this cannot be done on the server side, it has to be on client. So, after server code executes, it spits out the javascript to the browser, when then sets the hidden field value. I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: so you're saying I need a separate javascript function to set sendingRequest value to "0" on the clientside?  but this is a postback so surely I can just set the value using sendingRequest.Value = "0"; on the server side? I have access to the sendingRequest control on the server.

Comment: I believe the way the update panel work is basically the equivolent of scraping.  So it gets the full html back from the post back and parses it client side to replace the section in the update panel.  If the right JS files aren't loading though, this won't work.

Comment: ok, you are setting it to 0 on the server side & you are seeing 0 on the client. So, is this not what you wanted?

Comment: no.. initially it is set to 0 as specified in my XAML.  then I set it to "1" on the client and do a postback. Then on the server, it is "1" (as it has been set by the client), but then at the end of my updatepanel_Load I want to set it back to "0". So I use sendingRequest.Value = "0"; on the server.  but the value doesn't get set/updated on the client - it remains "1"

Comment: i suggest you try the page.registerscript method & see what happens. There's plenty of examples online. Be aware though, there are different versions of this method, so use the one that is right in your case.

Answer (score 0):

This similar scenario is done here successfully:

http://encosia.com/easily-refresh-an-updatepanel-using-javascript/

Ensure you are following the same steps - I can't see all of your code. Try with a label first to make sure it gets updated as a visible control. If that works then narrow it down with your hidden value to make sure the behavior isn't different for a hidden control.

Comment: Hi,I've replicated exactly the code on that site with a HiddenField and it works perfectly, but when I try to inegrate it with my actual page, it doesn't work - the value just won't get updated. I can't figure out why, but maybe it could be to do with there  being a second UpdatePanel on the page which is updating every 5 seconds? but I don't see why that would affect whether or not the updatepanel with the hiddenfield would update successfully.. :/

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue with three HiddenFields being set in Code-Behind, but their values were not set when polled from JQuery.

My issue turned out being that my Master Page uses an UpdatePanel, and in my ASP.Net Init event I was purposing that UpdatePanel with conditional rendering.

```
Private Sub Page_Init(sender As Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Init
    mstr = CType(Master, Site)

    'setup partial rendering so Log can update asynchronously
    scriptManager = CType(mstr.FindControl("ScriptManager1"), ScriptManager)
    scriptManager.EnablePartialRendering = True
    scriptManager.AsyncPostBackTimeout = 28800
    CType(mstr.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel).UpdateMode = UpdatePanelUpdateMode.Conditional
    CType(mstr.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel).ChildrenAsTriggers = False
End Sub
```

The issue was that I forgot to then call update on my panel after setting the HiddenFields. I had to do this because my button was a partial-postback control (UseSubmitBehaviour=False)

```
    hfParams.Value = paramlist.ToString()
    hfForms.Value = formlist.ToString()
    hfStartJob.Value = "True"
    CType(mstr.FindControl("UpdatePanel1"), UpdatePanel).Update()
```